# unable to run script contain * using ssh

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to run a script which have a wild card to search a file but failing as getting error like this:

```
bash: *: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "*")
```

This script is running fine on a machine but when try to use within ssh command it falling. Here is a command:

```
 ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@local-dev-server 'for i in *.version; do j=$(echo $i | cut -f 1 -d '.'); mv $i  $((j+1)).version; done;'
```

Can someone give me hint how i can fix this.

Comment: Is there a chance your non-interactive shell/setup is different than the interactive one? Perhaps `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@local-dev-server 'echo $SHELL'` is not bash?

Comment: No this is not a case it is a bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, if there are no `.version` files in the current directory, the code is trying to add 1 to `*.version` and that is an arithmetic error.

In a directory with no files, observe:

```
$ ls
$ for i in *.version; do j=$(echo $i | cut -f 1 -d '.'); mv $i  $((j+1)).version; done
bash: *: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "*")
```

If there was a number.version file, then the code would run:

```
$ touch 1.version
$ ls
1.version
$ for i in *.version; do j=$(echo $i | cut -f 1 -d '.'); mv $i  $((j+1)).version; done
$ ls
2.version
```

Also, the `cut` pipeline is unnecessary.  The code can be simplified to:

```
for i in *.version; do mv "$i" "$((${i%.version}+1)).version"; done
```

Further, to avoid the missing file error, use `nullglob`:

```
shopt -s nullglob; for i in *.version; do mv "$i" "$((${i%.version}+1)).version"; done
```

Comment: Thanks. This error misleading me. Can you give me one hint, if i want to get .version file which have a maximum number then how i can search this within current script? Actually i have a different version files like: 1.version, 2.version, 3.version using this script currently i rename all version files names but i am only interested to change maximum number file(3.version to 4.version) how i can search this in shell script ?

Comment: @user565, you might find [BashFAQ #3](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) useful for that -- some of the patterns are on-point (you can replace `[[ $foo -nt $bar ]]` with `(( ${foo%.version} > ${bar%.version} ))`, for example, to compare `foo` and `bar` numerically after stripping any `.version` suffix). Otherwise, it should be a separate question (if you can't find one that's on-point already).

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping the option in quotes:

```
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" user@local-dev-server 'for i in *.version; do j=$(echo $i | cut -f 1 -d '.'); mv $i  $((j+1)).version; done;'
```

Comment: Since the entire string is wrapped in outer quotes (and was in the OP's original version too), `'.'` is ending those outer quotes, adding `.` as an unquoted literal, then restarting them.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@local-dev-server `for i in `*.version`; do j=$(echo $i | cut -f 1 -d '.'); mv $i  $((j+1)).version; done;'
```

Comment: You're actually telling the shell to run `for i in` as a command on its own -- backticks don't nest without being escaped. (This is part of why `$()` is the preferred command substitution syntax; it's also POSIX-compliant, meaning that backticks would no longer exist at all if it weren't for backwards compatibility with ancient pre-POSIX shells). And even if the escaping was correct to have nested backticks running `*.version`, that would be invoking the first file to match the glob with the subsequent filenames passed to it as arguments.